# Getting SyntaxError: missing ; before statement during ajax JQuery Call

Tags: javascript

Code is:

```
var rootData = null;

$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:12345/request',  
data: rootData,
type: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'jsonp',
error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
success: function() { alert('OK'); }
});
```

I've got : 
"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"
I don't understand why !

Comment: I think error in some other place.post full function code

Comment: That piece of code looks good.

Comment: It's probably the returned code that has the problem. Use your browser's developer console to look at what's coming back from the GET request; it's probably not a proper JSONP response.

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur when you're not escaping a string properly and the JavaScript engine is expecting the end of your string already.

Check `rootData`, it might be causing this error. (I'm assuming `rootData` is set to `null` then populated with some data before sending the request)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the solution:

a Rest Server is on port 12345 (Tomcat)
and a Spring MVC server on port 8080 (Tomcat)

the request from MVC is

```
var treeData = null;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:12345/request',  
    data: treeData,
    type: 'GET',
    async:false,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
   success: function( treeData ) { ....
```

and the rest server must accept the cross domain request just by adding @CrossOrigin to it :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", produces =  { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String request()  { ....
```